# Conditional Jquery Hover on li tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following menu that changes to red if each of the menu items are hovered over.

I am currently having a hard time stopping the clicked menu item from hovering automatically if the mouse is left over the same menu item upon the new navigated page being loaded.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. The user mouses over and clicks a menu item.
2. If the users mouse is left over the clicked menu item, then the hover effect should not execute on the new navigated page, unless the user moves there mouse off the html element and back on it again.

How can this be done? - I have tried simply adding an if statement around the hover handler in the following code to check if any li tags have been hovered, but this doesn't work. Therefore I commented it out.

My computer will be going out the window very soon! :/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //if($('li').is(':hover').length == 0)
    //{

        $('li').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }, function() {
            $(this).css('background', 'none');
        })

    //}

})

</script>


<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any `:hover` selector in jQuery?

Comment: Your code doesn't even work

Comment: Guys, this is why I need help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have a hard time understanding what yoy want to achieve, but it appears something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/darevskaya/ybm74/42/):

```
(function ($) {
    //":hover" pseudo-selector can only work with single item, not with bunch of them. 
    // To determine if one of the matched items is hovered we can do this     
    $.fn.isAnyHovered = function () {
        return this.filter(function () {
            return $(this).is(":hover")
        }).length;
    };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        //unselect the item selected on page load  
        $(this).siblings('.forced_selected')
            .trigger('mouseleave')
            .removeClass('forced_selected');
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });


    //select the first item in list on load, if nothing else is hovered
    if(!$('li').isAnyHovered()) {
       $('li ').eq(0).trigger('mouseenter').addClass('forced_selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to explain.

Comment: You should try, or nobody'll be able to help. All the more i've included jsfiddle link in answer (http://jsfiddle.net/darevskaya/ybm74/42/)