# Don't Automatically Hover on new navigated page

Tags: jquery

I have the following menu that changes to red if each of the menu items are hovered over.

This menu shows on every page of my website.

**I have the following problem:**

If a user was to click a menu item (e.g. Menu 2), the page will navigation to the page set in the a tag (i.e page2.html)

If the user was to leave there mouse in the same position as it was in before the menu item was clicked (i.e. over the selected menu item), then the menu would automatically change to red again on the new page, as the jQuery hover code below will be activated.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour? Ideally I want users to have to mouse off of the menu item and then on it again before the menu item changes to red if the users mouse is still over the selected menu item after clicking one of the menu links.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
    })
})

</script>


<ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional Jquery Hover on li tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106517/conditional-jquery-hover-on-li-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's server-side task. You have to append class to `<li>`
Then, on page load, there will be class on that `<li>`
Which will give you effect you desire. And this way, it would be better to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` instead of `css()`. For example, let it be class `.active_link`, put in your CSS then control it as you need.

Comment: Thanks for this. Great help! But how would the server know which linked the user clicked on to apply the class to it?

Comment: If it's static HTML. Then mark it manually in every HTML file according to it's section.

If it's PHP + HTML, then catch $_GET['pageid'], for example: http://example.com/?pageid=5 .
`<ul>
<li class="<?php if(intval($_GET['pageid'])==5) { echo 'active_link' } ?>">Page #5</li>
</ul>`

This way you can get page id and match menu section by echoing class name. Page will be loaded with menu section selected.

More advanced and secure technique is to use .htaccess mod_rewrite module.